# At what levels do the various types of armour start to appear in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was wondering at what levels do the various types of armour start to appear?

For instance right at the beginning hide/studded is the more prevalent armor type (from memory) However I'm now level 18 and starting to see bits of Elven armour creep in to bandit chief loot, etc.

Comment: I remember seeing glass at around level 25 and ebony at 30

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Copied from [another post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/37665/122):

> The full Heavy Armor progression is (with very rough levels):
>
> - Iron (lv 1)
> - Steel (lv 6)
> - Dwarven (lv 12)
> - Steel Plate (lv 18)
> - Orcish (lv 25)
> - Ebony (lv 32)
> - Dragonplate (lv 40)
> - Daedric (lv 48)
>
> The full Light Armor progression is (with very rough levels):
>
> - Hide (lv 1)
> - Leather (lv 6)
> - Elven (lv 12)
> - Scaled (lv 27)
> - Glass (lv 36)
> - Dragonscale (lv 48)
>
> Clothing doesn't progress, rather the enchantments get more powerful as your level increases.

Source: [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/37665/122) by [Cloudancer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/13004/cloudancer)

Comment: I'm not sure that's accurate. Dragonscale is only available through crafting.

Comment: Both Dragonscale and Dragonplate can appear as loot, most of the time the pieces you find are enchanted with strong (Or sometimes not so strong) Enchantments, neither of them are only be obtained through Smithing. I found a Dragonplate Shield with 70% Frost Resistance as a loot item in the chest after killing The Caller in Fellglow Keep.

Comment: I have encountered ebony at level 31.

Comment: not true, it definitely appears as random loot from level ~50, but I think you might need the smithing *perk* before that starts to happen.

Answer (score 0):

They can appear at random times. Daedric won't be until the 40s but you will see the crafting materials for it really early on.

Answer (score -1):

you do not need the smithing perks or levels for the items to appear.  you can craft the items early on if you get a high enough smithing level.  and dragon armors are the last ones daedric are a bit weaker. i was seeing daedric items at like 48.  i got an ebony sword off a dragur deathlord at level 22.  sometime you get random shit at random levels

Answer (score -2):

It's not so much related to your level as to your skill level in smithing. I am, for example, about level 16 but have a reasonably high smithing skill (just over 60) and can smith Orcen armour and weapons

Comment: Justin, thanks for the answer but the question is not do with when I could smith the various armours but when you would start seeing them as loot/on enemies.