# What happens if I use the disable console command on dragons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have beaten both the main quest and Civil War quest and just want to chill around a bit, but every freaking time I fast travel a dragon pops up. I have like 20 unused dragon souls. What happens if I use `disable` on them to skip them? Is there any downside to abusing this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've already unlocked all the shouts you're interested in, the only thing you'll miss out on would be the rather valuable [dragon bones and scales](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/35297/274). If you don't care about those, feel free to use/abuse the `disable` console command all you want.