# What is the use of Dragon Bones in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do with Dragon Bones and Scales?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35297/what-can-i-do-with-dragon-bones-and-scales)

I have recently been slaying dragons in Skyrim, and I keep finding Dragon Bones and Scales. However, I have so far been unsuccessful in finding out what to do with them. I can't sell them for some reason.

Comment: @lunboks, what did you do to this question?  "10 characters added", but I don't see a difference; seems like a pointless bump to a closed question.

Comment: @NickT Well, I came across it and decided to undo my downvote, so I made a bogus edit and immediately changed it back. The revision was supposed to disappear, though. I probably stumbled upon some kind of bug here.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a master at smithing, you can use dragon scales and bones to make Dragon Armor. It is one of the best in the game. It requires either Daedric Smithing or Glass smithing AND 100 levels in smithing in order to create it.

Comment: It requires its own Dragon smithing Perk. Which can be obtained after daoedric or glass smithing.#