# Selling my dragon bones and scales

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, where is a good place to sell dragon bones and scales.  I'd like to know of a city and store that will take them.  I'm having trouble finding one.

Comment: Sell prices doesn't really vary per location iirc. Up your speech to help with prices.

Comment: Besides selling them, check this out as well: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35297/what-can-i-do-with-dragon-bones-and-scales?rq=1

Comment: Alchemy shops will buy the bones. I don't recall if they buy the scales too.

Answer (score 0):

Any general store in Skyrim will buy and sell Dragon Bones and Scales. You can find a list of these stores [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/General_Goods_Merchants_(Skyrim)).